# How to click a button or checkbox on a HTML page and reload the page AUTOMATICALLY

Tags: android, html

I would like to make a Android function that would analyze the web content and automatically click the submit button and reload the page for updating. I have already get the on the webview and find the line of button. BUT I do not know what to do next. Anyone got ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this by adding `button` with `js` to your `html` file:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Reload page</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    location.reload();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, this would work I think, But my function is for any website. I find the line of the button after fetching the content of the page. So I cannot add any button on the page. All of this should be initiated automatically

Answer (score 0):

Is it useful for you?
You can use this to check checkbox, input value,... whatever with your webview?
http://executeautomation.com/blog/hybridapplication-robotium/

Comment: This is incredible!! I never consider of something like this, I have learnt a lot.  I will try this, And let You know if there is any results.

Comment: Hi, with Robotium, you trigger run class from IDE (Eclipse, Android stuido...) with adb command line. If you want to trigger this from android application, you should research more for that.

Comment: Thanks, this is one of functions in my app, so I think there are still a lot to be done. Grateful anyway